# Is there a linear way to fit Exp+polynomial function?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, regression

I have function which looks like this:

```
f(x)= a Exp[x] + b x^2 + c x + d
```

Currently, I'm fitting it to data using nonlinear regression. The method works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Is there any method which would solve this problem in linear time?

Comment: Your model is still linear in the parameters a,b,c,d

Comment: Yea, I have my hessian filled with zeros

Comment: Was that a confirmation that you understand that you have a standard linear least-squares, i.e. no reason to use nonlinear least-squares

Comment: yes, actually, you are right. Apparently, I confused non-linearity of the function itself with the non-linearity of params